# Java GUI development alternative to swt or swing

Tags: java, user-interface

I am looking for an framework that works with xml and css as gui .I am basically from web application development so i prefer to customize the application using css something like zkoss in web framework.

Comment: have you tried JavaFx? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/howto/CSS-Tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

I think [javafx](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html) is what you want.

Comment: I cannot locate the sdk for linux is it officially unavailable?

Comment: 2.1 developer preview http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html