# A better gui design using java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am planning to develop an java application,so i am in search of some library's that can give  a pleasant look and feel and easy to customize.I tried swing but the look and feel is not much i expected and creating a look and feel is not so easy i think (i am not sure). i am from web development. In my previous question [Java GUI development alternative to swt or swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208301/java-gui-development-alternative-to-swt-or-swing) most guys recommend javafx and i am working on an 64 bit linux machine and javafx is not available for that. I need some advice ,

Better to create own look and feel library else suggest some good library for look and feel

Note:i tried nimbus look and feel.

Comment: Maybe you should try changing the L&F, check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available

Comment: @medopal See the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271) for a quick way to trial the installed PLAFs.

Comment: Note that generally, the user thinks the prettiest PLAF is given by [`getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getSystemLookAndFeelClassName%28%29).  Or to put that another way, give the user the PLAF they are expecting to see, one that looks just like the standard apps. on their OS.

Comment: Yeah... I think that the system look and feels look like crap, particularly so since the fonts aren't right... I think "Nimbus" is the way to go, combined with custom fonts. The (an)Droid fonts are really nice and free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can just give some suggestions that I am using in conjunction with Swing:

- JRibbon/Flamingo (Office 2007 like ribbons)
- Substance Look and Feel (works very well with JRibbon/Flamingo and is quite configurable, with a lot of predefined [skins](http://insubstantial.github.com/insubstantial/substance/docs/skins/overview.html))
- SwingX (additional/extended Swing components)

Note that for Substance there's a fork called [Insubstantial](https://github.com/Insubstantial) which contains also a Flamingo fork named Peacock.

Comment: I downloaded the files from the https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial and can u tell me how to build the library .

Comment: @Ramesh, I'd use one of the prebuilt libraries, e.g. those from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.github.insubstantial%22).

Comment: @Ramesh I would suggesting to download code_source, then search for Java folder test, there is Check.java (all better Custom Swing look and feels accesible from one JFrame), rest is up to you ( for users with reputation > 10k http://stackoverflow.com/a/9007004/714968 )

Answer (score 0):

JRibbon is the best replacement for menu and toolbar in a Java application. JRibbon gives a better user experiance then ordinary menubar and toolbar. It is look like rich UI Component in Java. JRibbon has all facility like Microsoft Office Ribbon have like application menu, taskbar.
[Source : JRibbon Tutorial](http://www.pointbaba.com/blog/11/jribbon-structure-and-simple-program)